# Cocoa - Trim all leading whitespace from NSString

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, whitespace, trim

(have searched, but not been able to find a simple solution to this one either here, or in Cocoa docs)

Q. How can I trim all *leading* whitespace only from an NSString?  (i.e. leaving any other whitespace intact.)

Unfortunately, for my purposes, NSString's stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet method works on both leading and trailing.

Mac OS X 10.4 compatibility needed, manual GC.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This creates an NSString category to do what you need.  With this, you can call `NSString *newString = [mystring stringByTrimmingLeadingWhitespace];` to get a copy minus leading whitespace.  (Code is untested, may require some minor debugging.)

```
@interface NSString (trimLeadingWhitespace)
-(NSString*)stringByTrimmingLeadingWhitespace;
@end

@implementation NSString (trimLeadingWhitespace)
-(NSString*)stringByTrimmingLeadingWhitespace {
    NSInteger i = 0;

    while ((i < [self length])
           && [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self characterAtIndex:i]]) {
        i++;
    }
    return [self substringFromIndex:i];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks very much John, and everyone who helped.  If I change the NSInteger line for 10.4 compatibility, it works just great. Cheers.

Comment: I forgot 10.4 doesn't have NSInteger.  Most of my work targets mobile devices, so it's been a while since I did anything for Tiger.  I'm glad it worked!

Comment: This is very helpful. One typo: "idx" should be "i" in the while loop.

Comment: Instead of doing your own while loop, use `NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`, `NSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`, or if you need flexibility go for an `NSScanner` object or even Reg Ex. See other answers to this question (they have less up-votes at the moment).

Answer (score 49):

This is another solution using Regular Expressions (requires iOS 3.2):

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"^\\s*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSString *result = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

And if you want to trim the trailing whitespaces only you can use `@"\\s*$"` instead.

Comment: Doesn't this trim both leading AND ending characters?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't notice that you want to remove the leading whitespaces only. Anyway, I changed the answer, check it again.

Comment: This solution is a lot more concise! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 37):

This code is taking blanks.

`NSString *trimmedText = [strResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`

`NSLog(@"%@",trimmedText);`

Comment: This will remove both leading and trailing whitespaces and newline characters, while the question is how to remove ONLY those at the beginning..

Answer (score 26):

Here is a very efficient (uses CoreFoundation) way of doing it (Taken from kissxml):

```
- (NSString *)trimWhitespace {
    NSMutableString *mStr = [self mutableCopy];
    CFStringTrimWhitespace((CFMutableStringRef)mStr);

    NSString *result = [mStr copy];

    [mStr release];
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Comment: The question is for trimming leading white space; this trims trailing too

Comment: @YosiTaguri, HOw will I call this method ? to trim my NSString

Comment: If you don't mind trimming trailing space too, then this is the perfect answer.

Comment: thanks for and answer that isn't a waste of CPU like many easy whitebelt answers  <3

Answer (score 21):

```
 NSString *myText = @"       foo    ";    
 NSString *trimmedText = [myText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
 NSLog(@"old = [%@], trimmed = [%@]", myText, trimmedText);
```

Comment: Perfect one. Nice answer . Please follow this post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do, and it doesn't involve categories!

```
NSString* outputString = inputString;
NSRange range = [inputString rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]
    options:0];
if (range.location == 0) 
    outputString = [inputString substringFromIndex: range.location + range.length];
```

This is much less code.

Comment: It's only less code if you only want to trim white space in one place in your application.

Comment: It would be faster too if you passed in the NSAnchoredSearch option

Comment: @JeremyP you could always put it this code in a category. It is still less code.

Comment: `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` returns the range of the *first* character in the string.  This is only going to remove the first whitespace character, not all leading.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really have much time to test this, and I'm not sure if 10.4 contains the UTF8String method for NSString, but here's how I'd do it:

NSString+Trimming.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Trimming)

-(NSString *) stringByTrimmingWhitespaceFromFront;

@end
```

NSString+Trimming.m

```
#import "NSString+Trimming.h"

@implementation NSString (Trimming)

-(NSString *) stringByTrimmingWhitespaceFromFront
{
    const char *cStringValue = [self UTF8String];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; cStringValue[i] != '\0' && isspace(cStringValue[i]); i++);

    return [self substringFromIndex:i];
}

@end
```

It may not be the most efficient way of doing this but it should work.

Comment: Where is the string that is getting trimmed in the above code? Do we definitely need to write a method for this?

Answer (score -6):

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: @" This string   "; becomes @"Thisstring"; . The originator stated that all other whitespace needed to remain intact.

Comment: Please read the question before you post an answer. The question is about trimming a string on both sides.