# IOS: nsstring leave some spaces

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, uitextfield

I have a particular problem:

in a NSSTring I have this value " abcdef ghil"
I want to check if first character is a space and delete it (with stringbyreplacing...?)
and in other space (from "f" to "g") I want insert a "-"

can you help me?

if it may be helpful; I take this string from a textfield...

Answer (score 4):

The following will do what you want, with the caveat that it will trim trailing whitespace as well as leading whitespace and not just a single leading or trailing whitespace character.

```
NSString *original = @" abcdef ghil";
NSString *trimmed = [original stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString *final = [trimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                                     withString:@"-"];
```

If you only want to remove leading whitespace then you should probably check out this previous question: [Cocoa - Trim all leading whitespace from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200521/cocoa-trim-all-leading-whitespace-from-nsstring)

**Update**: If you really only want to remove a single space at the beginning of the string then the following should work for you:

```
NSString *original = @"  abcdef ghil";

NSString *trimmed = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                        withString:@"" 
                                                           options:0 
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

NSString *final = [trimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                                     withString:@"-"];
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the first white space you can use:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

With a range created with NSMakeRange(0, 1), this is position 0 and length 1, you will replace the first " " with "".

With the output of this you can do simply:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

With this you will replace all " " with "-".