# 'Trimming' an NSString

Tags: cocoa

How do I 'trim' an NSString so that I can make a new string out of only a certain part of the old one?

For example is I have the string "Monday the 12th of September", how do I single out just the 'Monday' part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSRange`

Example:

```
NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 6;
    NSString *Secondstring = [Firststring substringWithRange:dayRange];
```

Provided 'Firststring' contains "Monday the 12th of September", printing 'Secondstring' will give just 'Monday'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200521/cocoa-trim-all-leading-whitespace-from-nsstring

Comment: Why that `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` call? It's completely superfluous. -1 until you remove it.

Comment: I take it I dont need the stringWithFormat thing anymore then?